# Pandas: Fill nan values in multiple columns with respective median values but accessing the columns using indices

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a DataFrame with 15 columns and 5000 rows.
In the DataFrame there are 4 columns that contain NaN values. I would like to replace the values with the median.

As there are several columns, I would like to do this via a for-loop.
These are the column numbers: 1,5,8,9.
The NaN values per column get the corresponding median.

I tried:

```
for i in [1,5,8,9]:
    df[i] = df[i].fillna(df[i].transform('median'))
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop, use a vectorial approach:

```
out = df.fillna(df.median())
```

Or, to limit to specific columns names:

```
cols = [1, 5, 8, 9]
# or automatic selection of columns with NaNs
# cols = df.isna().any()

out = df.fillna(df[cols].median())
```

or positional indices:

```
col_pos = [1, 5, 8, 9]
out = df.fillna(df.iloc[:, col_pos].median())
```

output:

```
   0    1  2    3    4  5  6    7    8  9
0  9  7.0  1  3.0  5.0  7  3  6.0  6.0  7
1  9  1.0  9  6.0  4.5  3  8  4.0  1.0  4
2  5  3.5  3  1.0  4.0  4  4  3.5  3.0  8
3  4  6.0  9  3.0  3.0  2  1  2.0  1.0  3
4  4  1.0  1  3.0  7.0  8  4  3.0  5.0  6
```

used example input:

```
   0    1  2    3    4  5  6    7    8  9
0  9  7.0  1  3.0  5.0  7  3  6.0  6.0  7
1  9  1.0  9  6.0  NaN  3  8  4.0  1.0  4
2  5  NaN  3  1.0  4.0  4  4  NaN  NaN  8
3  4  6.0  9  3.0  3.0  2  1  2.0  1.0  3
4  4  1.0  1  NaN  7.0  8  4  3.0  5.0  6
```

Comment: So df[cols].median() will work irrespective of whether cols have column indices or column names?

Comment: @RavindraS if you mean "position", then you would need to use `df.iloc[:, [1, 5, 8, 9]]`, but it's not clear from the description

Comment: By "These are the column numbers: 1,5,8,9." I think OP wants position-based indexing. It's better if you add that side note, just in case

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
df[[1,5,8,9]] = df[[1,5,8,9]].fillna(df[[1,5,8,9]].median())
```